# Unable to display two items in customview

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show items in my custom listview but I cant seem to get it to work. Activity just crashes. My purpose is to show both items in a listview. I am able to retrieve and store the necessary data from firebase into separate arraylists but unable to show them in the listview. Attaching all necessary codes below.

This is my customadapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList main;
    private final ArrayList sub;
    public CustomAdapter(Activity context,
                         ArrayList main, ArrayList sub) {
        super(context, R.layout.colortext, main);
        this.context = context;
        this.main = main;
        this.sub = sub;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.colortext, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textmain);
        TextView txtSub=rowView.findViewById(R.id.address);
        txtTitle.setText((Integer) main.get(position));
        txtSub.setText((Integer) sub.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

xml of custom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView1">
</ListView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textmain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textSize="23dp"
        android:textColor="#01B9F5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

mainactivity

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("locs").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        main.add(ds.child("title").getValue(String.class));
                        String g = main.toString();
                        sub.add(ds.child("addr").getValue(String.class));
                        String s = sub.toString();
                        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.listView1);


                        CustomAdapter adapter2 = new CustomAdapter(Location.this, main, sub);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter2);
                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your adapter add these methos to add item in your arraylist.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
     private final ArrayList mainList;
     private final ArrayList subList;

    public void addMain(Main main){
      mainList.add(main);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSub(Sub sub){
      subList.add(sub);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // manage your data in onBind
    @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int 
     position) {
        if(position < mainList.size() ){
            // display mainlist related data here
            // after adding items in mainlist, this will executed.

        }
        if(position > mainList.size()-1) {
            // display sublist related data here
        }
     }
}
```

You need to add mainList first for the condition in onbind will be met.
You can add data to your adapter like below.

```
// For example this is that path of your main lists
  DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("main"); 
  ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            // I assume you have a custom object. In this case let's just say `Main`
            Main main = dataSnapshot.getValue(Main.class);
            adapter.addMain(notification);
        }
        // ... other override methods
```

Comment: What is this Main here? ```public void addMain(Main main)```